# Let each thread of OpenMp use one core, when launched by mpirun

Tags: mpi, openmp, openmpi

I'm running MPI with OpenMP, I found that with this command, even though
OpenMP launched the thread number I defined, they all stick to one CPU core.

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
export OMP_PLACES=cores
export OMP_PROC_BIND=true
mpirun --host n1,n2,n3,n4 -np 4 a.out # the threads all stick to one core at each node 

 mpirun --host n1,n2,n3,n4 -np 4 grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latter on, I found this solution, it works out fine on my cluster:

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16

echo "Nodelist: $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST"
echo "CoerPerTask: $SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK"

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK
mpirun --map-by node:PE=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK ./main 14000
```

Answer (score 1):

With more search I found this --cpu-set  0-15 would allow OpenMp threads to bind to all 16 cores in my cluster.

```
mpirun --host n1,n2,n3,n4 -np 4 --cpu-set  0-15 grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-15
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-15
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-15
Cpus_allowed_list:      0-15
```

Comment: if you do not want any binding from Open MPI, simply `mpirun --bind-to none ...`

Comment: As @GillesGouaillardet is implicitly pointing out this is an issue that should be fixed at the MPI startup level. Having OpenMP ignore the limits imposed at that level is only going to cause you (or someone else) pain later when you decide it's better to have one MPI process per socket with OpenMP inside a socket (for instance). So you need to fix it at that level, and not force it at the OpenMP level...

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet @jimcownie thanks for that, I tried this ```mpirun --host e01-62,e01-64  -n 2  --bind-to none grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status 
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
``` But it seem didn't work

Comment: which version of Open MPI are you running?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet It should be 4.0.2, as I loaded ```module load gcc/8.3.0 openmpi/4.0.2 pmix```

Comment: you can confirm the version with `mpirun -V`. fwiw, i get the expected results (e.g. all cpus are allowed) in my environment with Open MPI 4.0.2. what if you `ssh e01-62 grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status` ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it ! yes, ```mpirun -V``` give me 4.0.2.
grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status only give me 0, but I used ``` salloc  --nodes=2  --exclusive ``` so I think it is exclusive for me to run it. I'll send email to sys admin of my cluster, hopping my admin will help me to solve it !

Comment: Open MPI should use `srun` instead of SSH. What is you `srun -N 2 -n 2 --cpu-bind=none grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status` **inside** your `salloc` ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I alloced 2 nodes, then ```$srun -N 2 -n 2 --cpu-bind=none grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status  
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
Cpus_allowed_list:      0
```
so they still both only have 1 cpu core

Comment: The last command shows all the cores available to the MPI tasks. You might want to retry with `salloc-N 2 -n 2 -c <cores_per_node>` and see if it helps. Contacting your sysadmin is the way to move forward here.